# Rust trait return type (Result)

Tags: rust, traits

This function creates a line segment by parsing the string defining the line segment.

Since there is an item to parse other than the line segment, I tried to use a trait.

I implemented it like below.

```
pub trait GeomParser<T> {
    fn parse(str_line: &str) -> Result<T, std::num::ParseFloatError>;
}

impl GeomParser<Segment> for Segment {
    fn parse(str_line: &str) -> Result<Segment, std::num::ParseFloatError> {
        let mut strs_iter = str_line.split_ascii_whitespace();

        strs_iter.next(); // L
        let start_x : f64 = strs_iter.next().unwrap().parse()?;
        let start_y : f64 = strs_iter.next().unwrap().parse()?;
        let end_x : f64 = strs_iter.next().unwrap().parse()?;
        let end_y : f64 = strs_iter.next().unwrap().parse()?;
        let width : f64 = strs_iter.next().unwrap().parse()?;

        let seg = Segment
        {
            start : Point { x: start_x, y: start_y },
            end : Point { x: end_x, y: end_y },
            width : width,
        };

        Ok(seg)
    }
}
```

Can I avoid using generics in the trait?

I would like to specify the type of the struct you implement as the return type?

```
pub trait GeomParser {
    fn parse(str_line: &str) -> Result<????, std::num::ParseFloatError>;
}

impl GeomParser for Segment {
    fn parse(str_line: &str) -> Result<Segment, std::num::ParseFloatError> {

...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Self`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.SelfTy.html):

```rust
pub trait GeomParser: Sized {
    fn parse(str_line: &str) -> Result<Self, std::num::ParseFloatError>;
}
```

It is the type implementing the trait.

Comment: Thank you. I added the following at the end and it built fine.

where Self: Sized;